# Can we mock private method with multiple arguments using PowerMockito?

Tags: mocking, powermockito, private-methods

Team,

I want to moclbelow method using Powermock
private void methodToMock(int param1,String param2,int param3)
{
}

I tried below which is not working
SampleClass spyObject = PowerMockito.spy(new SampleClass());
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(spyObject,"methodToMock", anyInt(),anyString(),anyInt());

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved by passing a variable instead of any().